# Getting JQuery DateTimePicker add-on to work

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, add-on

I've been trying to make [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) add-on work for over a week. I simply can't get it to show any dropdown

Here's my minimalist code:

**CSS (Richardson's unchanged one)**

```
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }
.ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
.ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#test').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="test" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="test">
```

Library including

```
<script src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JQuery libs are pulled from Google, CSS, Jquery CSS and Richardson's add-on are included in a separate file

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: What's happening in this line: `$('#test').datetimepicker();`? You didn't give too much info you know...

Comment: @gdoron $('#test').datetimepicker(); is a basic call to Richardson's add-on without any option, link above to see what it's supposed to do

Reference here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @H17737 You should add the script tags that includes the libraries.

Comment: @Fox32 updated, same directory and same name than the source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your addition of

```
class="hasDatepicker"
```

has caused it not to work.

I took your code and just removed that and it seems to work.  Example at:

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ioncache/LmUnr/3/)

Note: I linked directly to the github versions of the timepicker js and css files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like working fine now.
Don't know why this class was in the source

Comment: I looked at the jQuerUI datepicker source and it seems that the 'hasDatepicker' class is used internally by the datepicker plugin to indicate that an input already has a datePicker attached to it.

So by adding that class by hand, it causes the plugin not to instantiate a a datepicker object on the input even though technically there wasn't one there.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jquery UI for something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/Qdz4J/    For more help you can view [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) Hope this helps

Comment: Filled your link, I don't know why there's some jerky text showing up in the result